# how to click a button for an protractor e2e test?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to write an e2e test with protractor and click this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="clickThis()">Here</button>
```

My test looks like this:

```
 element(by.buttonText('Here')).click();
```

When I run protractor I get an error:

```
 Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using custom angular bootstrap or something? Protractor had trouble finding the angular app on that page.

Comment: try after putting a `browser.waitForAngular()` before you execute this step.

Comment: I forgot to say the button is on a modal that opens going to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of button text(which can be changed) use the xpath using the class.
This should work

```
element(by.xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-warning"]')).click();
```

if you still have synchronisation issues, set browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Comment: Please explain your code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Protractor consider [visible text](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) make sure your text is visible when the page loads.

If your modal takes time to appear that could be the reason. In that case make protractor wait for the modal to appear or use `by.binding` if you can.

Also make sure there is no CSS `text-transform` property applied to this text that could make it differ from "Here".